# Input keyevent in korean keyboard from adb shell

Tags: android, adb

I want to send Korean or other Non-English text to an Android device using adb shell. The input keyboard language selected is Korean, but it always displays characters in English with the `adb input keyevent` command. If I type from the device it works.

Same thing is working in emulator but not on a real device.